# Delete db row according to Javascript Result

Tags: php, javascript

How can I halt a `php` code block when `JS` confirm false result. My php code like this;

```
<?php
function func($msg){
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        var r = confirm('$msg');
        if(r==false){
           return false;
        }else{
           return true; 
        }
       </script>';
}

.
.

case "update":
func("Do you want to delete?");
mysql_query("UPDATE.....");
break; 


?>
```

When `func()` result is `false`, dont process `mysql_query()`

Comment: you seem to not know how php works. php is serversided and javascript is clientsided. php just serves content into the browser without waiting for anything between the browser and itself. you could not do it this way.

Comment: How can I do this?Is there a code like confirm in php?

Comment: no there is not. wich is what i said already. you can only do something like triggering the bottom part on a certain get or post variable. alternately you could put it into a seperate file and use location.href or ajax in javascript to call that second file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this approach it can not be done.
`Javascript` and `PhP` are different things. `Javascript` executes on client side end but php is server end. You would have to take into Account the power of Ajax. have a look at something similar

[How to Delete MySQL Rows with Ajax & jQuery](http://www.ehow.com/how_10043457_delete-mysql-rows-ajax-jquery.html)

[SIMPLE JQUERY AJAX DELETE WITH CONFIRMATION](http://www.digitalbart.com/blog/simple-jquery-ajax-delete-with-confirmation/#)

Comment: accept the ans so others who have same problem get to know what is the solution